# How to assign initialization list to matrix or 2d array along with row and col indication?

Tags: c++, matrix

I am currently using `std::initializer_list` to make my 2d matrix take value directly from the curly bracket.

eg: `Matrix tmp = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};` *works*

What I actually wanted to do was:

eg: `Matrix tmp(2,3) = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};` *does not work*

My question is:

Is this doable using initialization list? Because when I try, I get error: expected ';' at end of declaration, and also is it good api design to let my user use my matrix class that way?

Comment: could you add your Matrix struct/class definition? I doubt you declare a constructor take (int, int) argument.

Comment: the first you use initializer-list constructor, and the second look like an assignment to intializer list.

Comment: @khôinguyễn you are right .. I think if I write operator overloading for operator=(std::initializer<...) it might work . I will try and let you know. Thank you for your thought

Comment: Since your initialize constructor fron 1st statement work well. You should declare a copy assignment operator=(const Matrix&); so your second statement will work like this: construct a Matrix from the right hand side of = , then assign it to the left :) The initializer list should be use only for initalization

Comment: Can you be more clear what it is you want?  Pass both runtime dimensions and data?  Use that exact syntax?  What exactly are your requirements?  Would `Matrix m(2,3, {{1,2,3},{7,8,9}});` do?  What must happpen if dimensions and list sizes disagree?